# Операторы из mysql в php

Tags: php, mysql, операторы

Можно ли использовать оператор LIKE который в mysql запросах, для чего-то другого например для того что бы просто сравнить переменные.
Типо:

```
if (q LIKE a)
{
 echo 'good';
}
```

Comment: А что вы подразумеваете под `LIKE` ? Приведите примеры. А то мне не понятно true LIKE 'true' или нет

Comment: Формально можно, конечно, изобразить какую-нить дурь типа `mysql_qiery("SELECT '$q' LIKE '$a%' AS result;"` и проверку, насколько результат TRUE - но это совсем за гранью разумного...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Операторы из SQL в PHP использовать нельзя.

В РНР есть свои операторы. Вместо LIKE можно использовать `strpos()`.

Answer (score 0):

В php своих операторов и так достаточно для сравнения, выборки, условных операторов , коннекторы к базе данных и др.

```
$a = 'How are you?';

if (\strpos($a, 'are') !== false) {
    echo 'true';
}
```

Написано с мобильного , сорри  :)

Answer (score -1):

Уж если так хочется, можно придумать функцию вида:

```
function LIKE($a,$b){
  $res=false;
  if (strpos($a, $b) !== false) {$res=true;}
  return $res;  
};

if (LIKE("aaa","a")) echo "TRUE";
```

;)